# Why am I getting forms like this?

Tags: php, mysqli, insert, send

I'm trying to create insert, update and delete relate to shopping, all of them are working fine except update page.

Please see sample code of list of product from  index.php page ...

```
<?php


        $sql = "SELECT product_id, product_name, product_category, product_retail_price, product_price, product_detail FROM  product";
        $result_db = $db->query($sql) or die('Error perform query!');

        ?>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>product name</th>
                <th>product category</th>
                <th>product retail price</th>
                <th>price</th>
                <th>detail</th>
                <th>Update</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
                <th>Insert</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            while ($r = $result_db->fetch_object()) {
                $update = "update_form.php?product_id={$r->product_id}&
                 product_name={$r->product_name}&
                 product_category=$r->product_category&
                 product_retail_price={$r->product_retail_price}&
                 product_price={$r->product_price}&
                 product_detail={$r->product_detail}";

                $delete = "delete.php?product_id={$r->product_id}";

                $insert = "insert.php";

                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>' . $r->product_id . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $r->product_name . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $r->product_category . '</td>';
                 echo '<td>' . $r->product_retail_price . '</td>';
                 echo '<td>' . $r->product_price . '</td>';
                  echo '<td>' . $r->product_detail . '</td>';
                echo "<td><a href='{$update}'>Update</a></td>";
                echo "<td><a href='{$delete}'>Delete</a></td>";
                echo "<td><a href='{$insert}'>Insert</a></td>";
                echo '</tr>';
            }
            $db->close();
            ?>    
        </table>
    </body>
```

As you can see above code where it said

```
while ($r = $result_db->fetch_object()) {
                    $update = ......
```

This sending the data of relate to product using "product_id" sending sending to the updateform.php page ... that updateform.php page is the code showing

```
<body>
  <form action="update.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" value="<?= $_GET['product_id'] ?>" name="product_id"/>

  product name: <input type="text" name="product_name" value="<?= $_GET['product_name'] ?>">

  product category: <input type="text" name="product_category" value="<?= $_GET['product_category'] ?>">

  product retail price: <input type="text" name="product_retail_price" value="<?= $_GET['product_retail_price'] ?>">

  product price: <input type="text" name="product_price" value="<?= $_GET['product_price'] ?>">
  product detail: <input type="text" name="product_detail" value="<?= $_GET['product_detail'] ?>">

            <input type="submit" name="submit">
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the code, the updateform.php showing the text field with `<?= $_GET['xxxxxx'] ?>"`

Why am I getting this result?
Is it this code?

```
   $update = "update_form.php?product_id={$r->product_id}&
                     product_name={$r->product_name}&
                     product_category=$r->product_category&
                     product_retail_price={$r->product_retail_price}&
                     product_price={$r->product_price}&
                     product_detail={$r->product_detail}";
```

Is it the right code to get right information from database using "product_id" number?  Is there better code to write than this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using :

```
<?php echo $_GET['xxxxxx']; ?>
```

and if it works, it means that in your php configuration the use of short opening tags is restricted. meaning no

Comment: I changed that from = to php like this <?php echo $_GET['xxxxxx']; ?> and this time is solved but can't get data from database.... what did i missed!